# How to setup network on new installation of Centos 7

Tags: centos, networkmanager

I have just installed Centos 7 on VMware as a quest on Windows. Surprisingly centos 7 does not install the network (i.e. no internet) after install (unlike previous versions of centos). I have gone through the centos forum and have not been able to find an answer.
When I try

```
nmcli d
```

I get

```
DEVICE TYPE STATE CONNECTION
lo loopback unmanaged --
```

I have tried several other commands and they take me nowhere.
I copied the following rpm packages from the installation iso image:

```
NetworkManager-1.0.6-27.e17.i686.rpm
NetworkManager-config-routing-rules-1.0.6-27.e17.i686.rpm
NetworkManager-server-1.0.6-27.e17.i686.rpm
NetworkManager-devel-1.0.6-27.e17.i686.rpm
```

I installed these with

```
rpm -Vuh "package"
```

The first three showed an indication of being installed. The fourth did not install due to dependencies.

```
nmcli d
```

gives the same result.

```
system-config-network
```

gives command not found.
I am really stuck. I see the same question here [enter link description here](https://www.centos.org/Forums/viewforum=php?f=50)
posted on 13th January 2017, 22 views, no reply.
Please help, how can I setup an internet connection?

```
lspci -nn |grep -i net
```

gives

```
02:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200] Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] [1022:2000] (rev 10)
```

Here is the output of output of

```
lspci | grep -i net

02:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200] Advanced Micro Devices Inc. 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] [1022:2000] rev 10)
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401] Ensoniq ES1371/Creative Labs CT2518/ES1373 [1274:1371] (rev 2)
02:03.0 USB controller [0c03]:VMware USB2 EHC1 controller [15ad:0770]
```

Comment: From the output of `nmcli d` it seems the NIC is not recognized, which may be due to missing driver. Could you add `lspci | grep -i net` to your question.

Comment: Go to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-"network interface name" and created it. You can define static ip address or DHCP.Using systemctl to enable network and service network start. Dont forget define hostname /etc/hosts

Comment: @Thomas is correct, you can also verify that with the `ip link` command which will list the interfaces. if you don't see your NIC there try replacing the virtual nic via VMware interface to a more generic one like the `Intel Pro`

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what I have in  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts is ifcfg-lo. Can you assist me with the steps to follow. Do I create another file "ifcfg-anyname" ? what should be the contents of that file. I have done ip link before this post. output was "lo:,LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> ...and more". I also tried service "NetworkManager satrt" and "chkconfig NetworkManager on" I was prompted for password and it seems to have ok, no complaint.

Comment: The full output of `ip link` or `ip address` would very helpful. With that we could identify the next steps.

Comment: ip link gives 1:lo:,LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state unknown mode DEFAULT link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 and ip address gives the same as above, plus inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid lft forever preferred_lft forever inet6:: 1/128 scope host

Comment: Please to see which driver is in use `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2

Comment: output of `lspci | grep -i net`

Comment: @Bahamut see edit at the end of my question. I was not able to post the edit as a comment. Adding k to -nn gives the following extra line: Subsystem Ensoniq AudioPCI 64V/128 /Creative CT4810/CT5803/CT5806 [Sound blaster PCI][1274:1371]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I solved it by adding `ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"` to .vmx file which is by default located in Virtual Machines\YourVM.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this worked for me:

Re: CentOS 7 network install on VMWare Workstation problem

([Quote](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47724#p203585))

> Postby Duke Nukem » 2014/08/13 21:29:13
>
> OK, I think this may be a 32-bit/64-bit issue of some kind ? Centos 7 is now 64-bit only.
>
> I'm using Windows 8 64-bit but its not clear (to me) what the VMWare host itself is running (note: the VMWare UI itself is, I believe, always 32-bit regardless of the guest OS it is running).
>
> Anyhow, in VMWare, when selecting the OS do *not* select Centos, instead select "Other Linux 3.x kernel 64-bit". Doing that I can now select a network device and it appears to work (I can log in via a PuTTy terminal), though not sure what the side effects of this choice might be - guess I'm about to find out :-).
>
> Also during install config of network/hostname I had to switch the connection on and also added a tick for "Automatically connect to this network when it is available".
>
> TTFN,
>    Jon
>
> PS: I also ticked the "Replicate physical network connection state", not sure if that is necessary but hey, it is working.
>   Attachments fix2.jpgNetwork optionsfix2.jpg (30.58 KiB) Viewed 82167 timesfix.jpgSelecting the OSfix.jpg (24.69 KiB) Viewed 82167 times

Comment: When creating CentOS VMs, I choose RedHat. Basically CentOS is RHEL without the support license. Never had an issue, and we have a few hundred VMs at my day job.